# Modify Swagger Definition Names for MVC API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, swagger, swashbuckle

I would like to modify the Swagger schema object names that are auto generated for my MVC application.

For example, I have number of entities like `EmployeeModel` or `CompanyModel` objects that are accessible via our REST endpoints

However, it's not necessary or desired that the Swagger definition contains the word "Model" after each entity name. They should be known only as Employee or Company -- see example in screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the **SchemaId** function available in your `SwaggerConfig.cs` file in the `EnableSwagger` method as follows:

```
c.SchemaId(t =>
{
    c.SchemaId(t => t.FullName.EndsWith("Model") ? t.FullName.Replace("Model", String.Empty) : t.FullName);
});
```

This methods allows you to override Swashbuckle default behavior and set complex type names properly.

My sample addresses directly the removela of the *"Model"* part of your boject names, but could be using more complex setup.

Answer (score 0):

What library are you using to build you swagger shema? Take a look at [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi#modifying-generated-schemas) . This allows to build swagger shema automatically for your app (by using xml-documentation) and is flexible for customization. See "**Modifying Generated Schemas**" in documentation.